# How to disable database connection for local development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm currently developing my Rails app on my local machine. I have no DB installed on my local machine, and I'm sending my codes to remote testing server which actually runs the app in development mode.

Until yesterday all commands like `rails g model foo` or `rails g controller foo` on my local machine worked with no errors.

But now all of `rails generate` commands started to fail due to no database connections. I think the direct reason is because I made some changes to my app configs, but I'm not sure where the changes are.

I guess the wrong part is that `rails generate` commands are always invoking `active_record`
 which always verifies the DB connection.

---

Now, my question is:

Is there any way to temporally disable `rails` to verify the database connections, for local development(which has no DB connection available)?

I tried removing `config/database.yml` but it didn't help.

Comment: Obviously this was such a newbie question. I actually wasn't understainding how to develop an application. See the comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local development environment needs to have the same sort of facilities as the application requires. If you have database backed models then you need a database, preferably the same one as used when deploying the application so your tests are useful.

It really shouldn't be a big deal to set up a database for local development.  Depending on your platform there are usually many different easy to use installers available.

Uploading your code changes to a remote server for execution is a really dysfunctional development model. If you have no alternative, it might be best to create the models on the remote system and pull them down to edit.

Comment: I might think this is quite off-topic, but could you give me an advice: I understand that my approach is quite dysfunctional. But is there a better way for team development? I think that preparing local servers for each users might take a lot of time.

Comment: Postgres and MySQL are dead simple to set up. That each developer has their own database is essential for tests and working on different scema versions. It's absolutely the only way to do it. Most developers I know have at least one local DB, sometimes several different types. It's not really a big deal.

Comment: Ah.. actually I have misread the answer. Maybe I'll just try installing DB for local machine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are things like [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) that can make your life easier. It doesn't have to be a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That might help a lot. I'll take look at it.